# Prevent KeyDown event identify SendKeys

Tags: c#

I want to make a program to simulate textentry if user press the keys "D1 - D0" and simulate some numbers if user pressed the function keys..

Here is the code I have tried.

```
if (e.KeyData == Keys.D1){
    SendKeys.Send("simulate this text entry");
}
if (e.KeyData == Keys.F12){
    SendKeys.Send("123");
}
```

But the problem is when I press the F12 button, the KeyDown event identify the first "1" as the "D1" key and sends both "123" and "simulate this text entry"

How can I prevent this problem ?

Comment: @Okuma.Scott No. I dont press those keys simultaneously. e.KeyData identify if the user pressed the D1 key.. (Only D1. Not D1 with shift or any other key like ctrl or alt). And what did you mean by the structure of my event ? I dont get it..

Comment: There's no point in sending keystrokes to yourself, you can simply update the Text property of whatever control is the intended target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved the problem.. :) Here is the code.. Have to use "SendKeys.Flush()" in this task...

```
private bool IgnoreKeys = false;

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyData == Keys.D1) && (!IgnoreKeys))
        {

            SendKeys.Send("Simulate this text" + "{ENTER}");

        }
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.F12)
        {
            IgnoreKeys = true;

            SendKeys.Send("123");
            SendKeys.Flush();

            IgnoreKeys = false;
        }
```

This prevents the KeyDown event considering "1" in the text "123" as the key "D1"

Idea is Idle_Mind's :) Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

When you go to send the keys, you'd have to set a flag so you know to ignore the characters being sent.  Additionally, you'd need to know when to turn the flag back on.  This could be done by setting a variable to the length of the value being sent, and then incrementing a counter with each detected key.  This isn't foolproof as the user could hit keys in rapid succession (or hold a key down) and you wouldn't know if the keypress was a result of user interaction or from your simulation.

Here's the basic idea:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool IgnoreKeys = false;
    private int target = 0;
    private int counter = 0;

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IgnoreKeys)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.D1)
            {
                Send("simulate this text entry");
            }
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.F12)
            {
                Send("123");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            counter++;
            if (counter == target)
            {
                IgnoreKeys = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Send(string entry)
    {
        IgnoreKeys = true;
        counter = 0;
        target = entry.Length;
        SendKeys.Send(entry);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that using `SendKeys.Send( ... )` there is no way your program can tell the difference between your sent keys and the user's keyboard input.

When you send the keys "123" it is the same as if the user pressed the 1, 2, and 3 keys.
Because you're listening for the 1 key, that event fires and catches the '1' sent by sendkeys.

If possible, try to append text to the content you're trying to "simulate textentry" into and avoid sendkeys. 
Otherwise consider making your number hotkeys alt/ctrl-combinations such as this:

```
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.D1)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("simulate this text entry");
            e.Handled = true;        
        }
```

That will prevent this event from being fired when you press F12 and send "123" (because ctrl is not pushed).

Comment: Sorry :( No way to append the text. Im going to send the text entry into the game chat. The game doesnt even support the copy paste command. SendKeys is the only way.. The key must be a single key to send message easily while fighting a war. By the way I think @Idle_Mind 's answer below can help me to solve the problem.. Still thinking.. :) Thanks for your respond.